# Why can't I change the text content of this element?

Tags: javascript, html, text, element, getelementbyid

This is the HTML element which I am trying to replace the text content of:

```html
<h1 id="lastLogin"> </h1>
```

This is my JS:

```js
if (localStorage.getItem("lastLogin") == undefined) {
  document.getElementById("lastLogin").textContent =
    "Welcome, this is your first time logging in.";
} else {
  document.getElementById("lastLogin").textContent =
    "Welcome, the last time you logged in was on " +
    localStorage.getItem("lastLogin");
}
```

When I run this I get an Uncaught TypeError: "Cannot set properties of null (setting 'textContent')"

Comment: Where in the page is the JS code, and how is the code triggered to run? The JS could be running before the HTML has been rendered.

Comment: I put the JS in a function to run on the click of a button, this solved my problem, Thank you.